# Angularjs - Passing data to factory method not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I just started out coding angular, and I'm not sure what I'm exactly doing wrong.

I have a factory with a method that uses an $http get:

```
angular.module('d3_survey')
.factory('currentSurvey', ['$http', function($http) {
    return{
        sweep : function(number) {
            console.log('resources/currentSurvey/' + number + '.json');
            return $http.get('resources/currentSurvey/' + number + '.json').then(function (response) {
                return response;
            });
        }
     }
}]);
```

I thought that I could do this since sweep is a closure and everything and it would still have access to $http. I resolve the service in my ui-router config.

```
resolve : {
                        surveyDetails : ['surveyQuestions', function(surveyQuestions){
                           return surveyQuestions.all();
                        }],
                        messages : ['currentSurvey', function(currentSurvey) {
                            return currentSurvey;
                        }]
                      }
```

I inject "messages" onto my controller and try to call the sweep method:

```
var messages = $scope.currentSurvey.sweep('1');

$scope.result = JSON.stringify(messages);
```

But when I bind $scope.result to my view I get something weird on the page:

```
{"$$state":{"status":0}}
```

I saw other questions where some people have done a further .then() on the result of the factory method, but even this didn't work out.

This is what I see on the console, but it doesn't make any sense:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token m
at Object.parse (native)
at pc (http://localhost:63342/SurveyTool/js/angular.min.js:14:208)
at Zb (http://localhost:63342/SurveyTool/js/angular.min.js:76:379)
at http://localhost:63342/SurveyTool/js/angular.min.js:77:237
at s (http://localhost:63342/SurveyTool/js/angular.min.js:7:302)
at Zc (http://localhost:63342/SurveyTool/js/angular.min.js:77:219)
at c (http://localhost:63342/SurveyTool/js/angular.min.js:78:349)
at http://localhost:63342/SurveyTool/js/angular.min.js:112:20
at l.$eval (http://localhost:63342/SurveyTool/js/angular.min.js:125:305)
at l.$digest (http://localhost:63342/SurveyTool/js/angular.min.js:122:398) angular.js:11939
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just return from asynchronous operation like AJAX request. In your case `currentSurvey.sweep` returns a [Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) object, so you should use its API to chain callback with `then` method. This callback will be invoked once data is available:

```
messages.sweep('1').then(function(response) {
    $scope.result = JSON.stringify(response.data);    
});
```

Another thing, you don't really need to provide `messages` key in resolve section of the router config. You can inject `currentSurvey` service directly to controller.

Comment: Hey i did try with the then as well. That time even the {"$$state":{"status":0}} went away. I was still stuck with the same trace in the console.

Comment: oh i just realized what the console log was about. Its a mistake in my json file itself. It does work with the .then() Thanks!!